# addBetweenCondition use in YII

Tags: php, sql, yii, between

In Normal situations we use the BETWEEN to find the 2 values in 1 column and in YII we can use it like below :

```
$criteria->addBetweenCondition('attributeName', 'column 1', 'column 1');
```

But my question is how can we use this addBetweenCondition for 1 value with  2 column ? some thing like :

```
  $criteria->addBetweenCondition('value', 'column 1', 'column 2');
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider:

```
$criteria->addCondition('`column 1` <= 'value' AND 'value <= `column 2`);
```